# Is there any way to remove file sort in mysql when comparing two columns?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

My query appears as follow:

```
SELECT * FROM table 
WHERE field like '%keyword%' 
ORDER BY (vote_up-vote_down) DESC
```

The sorting is running up my sql resources, is there any way to improve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**NO** for your case, as mysql need to evaluate the expression and calculate the actual result of `vote_up-vote_down`.

Thus, file-sort is inevitable

You can check the following for a faster performance on sort

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/order-by-optimization.html

> If you want to increase ORDER BY speed, check whether you can get MySQL to use indexes rather than an extra sorting phase. If this is not possible, you can try the following strategies:
>
> Increase the size of the sort_buffer_size variable.
>
> Increase the size of the read_rnd_buffer_size variable.
>
> Use less RAM per row by declaring columns only as large as they need to be to hold the values stored in them. For example, CHAR(16) is better than CHAR(200) if values never exceed 16 characters.
>
> Change tmpdir to point to a dedicated file system with large amounts of free space. Also, this option accepts several paths that are used in round-robin fashion, so you can use this feature to spread the load across several directories. Paths should be separated by colon characters (“:”) on Unix and semicolon characters (“;”) on Windows, NetWare, and OS/2. The paths should be for directories in file systems that are located on different physical disks, not different partitions on the same disk.